# how do I check the data type of the given input in cpp?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I give 10 means it should print it is a integer 
If I give 10.2 means it should print it is a float
If I give 'a' means it should print it is a char

Comment: Write the code to do it. Accept the input as a plain string. Strip off leading whitespace. If the remaining text consists of strictly digits, with an optional minus sign, it must be an integer. If it has an optional minus sign, and at least one digit interspersed with exactly one period, followed by an optional "e", optional plus or minus, and at least one more digit, it must be a floating point. You must write all the code to implement this logic. There is no library funciton that will do it for you.

Comment: Input is merely text. Read it and decide what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Read the input as a `std::string` first.

Then, pass the string to [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and if it consumes the whole string without error, print the resulting integer.

Otherwise, pass the string to [`std::stof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) , and if it consumes the whole string without error, print the resulting float.

Otherwise, print the string as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type_traits and template specialization to achieve this. Please see this example for more info:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_integer{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<>
struct is_integer<int>{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_char{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<>
struct is_char<char>{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
void printType(T t){
    if(is_integer<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout<<"Value is integer"<<std::endl;
    }
    else if(is_char<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout<<"Value is char"<<std::endl;
    }
    else if(std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout<<"Value is float"<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    char j = 'a';
    float k = 10.2f;

    printType(i);
    printType(j);
    printType(k);

    return 0;
}
```